# How to get name of sorted column in MudDataGrid from SortedBy Func<T, object>

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

Razor code:

```
<MudDataGrid Sortable="true" Hideable="true" RowsPerPage="10"
        ServerData="LoadServerData">
        <Columns>
            <Column T="PersonDto" Field="@nameof(PersonDto.Birthday)" Title="Birthday"/>
            <Column T="PersonDto" Field="@nameof(PersonDto.Description)" Title="Description"/>
            <Column T="PersonDto" Field="@nameof(PersonDto.Email)" Title="Email"/>
        </Columns>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudDataGridPager T="PersonDto" RowsPerPageString="Elements per page" PageSizeOptions="PageSizeOptions"></MudDataGridPager>
        </PagerContent>
    </MudDataGrid>
```

and C# method:

```
private async Task<GridData<PersonDto>> LoadServerData(GridState<PersonDto> state)
{
        var pageSize = state.PageSize;
        var pageIndex = state.Page + 1;
        var sortBy = "";
    
    if (state.SortBy != null)
    {
        sortBy = state.SortBy;// "what should I write here";

    }
    
    var result = await PersonService.GetPersonsAsync(pageSize, pageIndex, sortBy);
    
    GridData<PersonDto> data =  new()
    {
        Items = result,
        TotalItems = result.Count
    };

    return data;
}
```

My question is how to receive sorted Column as a string from **state.SortBy(Func<T, object>)**?
SortBy is a Func<> and I have no idea how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround because I also don't understand the point of the `Func<T, object>` in remote backend request scenario:

```
<Column T="PersonDto" 
        Field="@nameof(PersonDto.Birthday)" 
        Title="Birthday"
        SortBy="@(_=>nameof(PersonDto.Birthday))"
/>
```

```cs
private async Task<GridData<PersonDto>> LoadServerData(GridState<PersonDto> state)
{
    var pageSize = state.PageSize;
    var pageIndex = state.Page + 1;
    var sortBy = "";
    
    if (state.SortBy != null)
    {
        sortBy = state.SortBy((PersonDto)default!).ToString();
    }
```